# 2 parameters (id and page) in url with mod_rewrite?

Tags: mod-rewrite

With my current code I can convert the URL:

```
www.midomain.com/all.php?id=3
```

In this URL (I can perfectly get the 'id' with php):

```
www.midomain.com/all/3/
```

But how do I convert the URL:

```
www.midomain.com/all.php?id=3&page=2
```

In this URL?:

```
www.midomain.com/all/3/2/
or:
www.midomain.com/all/3/page-2/
```

This is my actual code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^all/([^/\.]+)/?$ all.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend the regex to match the url you're after and pass the extra match as the page param.

Something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^all/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ all.php?id=$1&page=$2 [L]
```